# Automatically strip the number in front of python codes when pasting

Tags: python-2.7, automation, coding-style

When I am reading an ebook or website, instead of inefficiently writing all the codes, I can obviously copy and paste the python codes. But about sometimes the format of the python code has a **number, a period, and a space** in front of the actual python code lines, I wonder if there is any technique/tools to remove them automatically? For example, from...

```
68. # File name: floatlayout.py
69. 
70. from kivy.app import App
71. from kivy.uix.floatlayout import FloatLayout
```

to ...

```
# File name: floatlayout.py

from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.floatlayout import FloatLayout
```

Comment: Write a Python script to do that!

Comment: Just strip everything before the first space.

Comment: LOL, true and that I can do

Comment: If you use Textmate, you can hold the option key and vertically select the those numbers and delete them all at once.

Comment: Does Textmate have a windows version? I don't see it. I use sublime text.

Comment: Just saw that sublime text can use middle mouse button for vertical selection, thanks for the lead guys, https://www.sublimetext.com/docs/2/column_selection.html

Comment: @KubiK888 Wow that's cool! I didn't know you could use the middle button for that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 def remove_spaces(file_path):
     with open(file_path) as myfile, open('newfile.py', mode='w+') as newfile:
        for line in myfile:
            idx = line.find(' ')
            if idx < 0 or idx + 1 >= len(line) or is_int(line.strip()[:-1]):
                newfile.write('\n')
                continue

            newfile.write(line[idx+1:] + '\n')

def is_int(str):
    try: int(str)
    except: return False

    return True
```

Comment: This is wonderful, it will probably take me a couple hours to figure it out, could you please let me know how I can educate/train myself to program in python as fast as you?

Comment: @KubiK888 [This](http://learnpythonthehardway.org/book/) could help. I could post more extensive comments explaining each step, or could let you figure it out. Would that help?